# UITableView self sizing stackView height Constraints issue

Tags: uitableview, autolayout, uistackview, snapkit

I have a problem Self sizing Cell problem.
I want make layout like Feed Content with attached Image like twitter

| Profile Image | - | Nickname Label | - | date Label | - | menuBarButton |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vertical - StackView |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| ㄴ | Content Label |  |  |  |  |  |
| ㄴ | FSPager CollectionView |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Horizontal - StackView |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Cell height is fine with image or none image cell, but debug console tells the broken Constraints

error is...

```
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x281fab000@FeedCell.swift#207 UILabel:0x134433be0.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x134437b90.top + 10.0>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x281fab060@FeedCell.swift#208 UILabel:0x134433be0.height == 25.0>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x281fab5a0@FeedCell.swift#236 UIStackView:0x1344370d0.top == UILabel:0x134433be0.bottom + 10.0>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x281fab840@FeedCell.swift#243 UIStackView:0x134437a00.top == UIStackView:0x1344370d0.bottom + 10.0>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x281fab960@FeedCell.swift#245 UIStackView:0x134437a00.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x134437b90.bottom - 10.0>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2819478e0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x1344370d0.top == UILabel:0x1344341a0.top   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281947930 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[UILabel:0x1344341a0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x1344370d0 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2819777a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x134437b90.height == 44   (active)>"
```

and my Code is

```
    profileImageView.snp.makeConstraints {
      $0.leading.equalToSuperview().offset(10)
      $0.top.equalTo(nicknameLabel)
      $0.size.equalTo(50)
    }
    
    nicknameLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
    nicknameLabel.snp.makeConstraints {
      $0.top.equalToSuperview().offset(10)
      $0.height.equalTo(25)
      $0.leading.equalTo(profileImageView.snp.trailing).offset(10)
    }
    
    dateLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    dateLabel.snp.makeConstraints {
      $0.centerY.equalTo(nicknameLabel)
      $0.height.equalTo(25)
      $0.leading.equalTo(nicknameLabel.snp.trailing)
    }
    
    menuBarButton.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
    menuBarButton.snp.makeConstraints {
      $0.top.equalTo(nicknameLabel)
      $0.leading.equalTo(dateLabel.snp.trailing).offset(10)
      $0.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
    }
    
    imagePagerView.snp.makeConstraints {
      $0.size.equalTo(250)
    }
    attachmentView.snp.makeConstraints {
      $0.top.equalTo(nicknameLabel.snp.bottom).offset(10)
      $0.leading.equalTo(nicknameLabel)
      $0.trailing.equalTo(menuBarButton)
    }
    
    footerStackView.snp.makeConstraints {
      $0.top.equalTo(attachmentView.snp.bottom).offset(10)
      $0.leading.equalTo(nicknameLabel)
      $0.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
    }
```

[image]

and my tableView code is..
`

```
   lazy var tableView = UITableView().then {
    $0.register(FeedCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: FeedCell.identifier)
    $0.refreshControl = refreshControl
    $0.backgroundView = EmptyView(text: "피드가 존재하지 없습니다.")
    $0.backgroundView?.isHidden = true
    $0.backgroundColor = .white
    $0.estimatedRowHeight = 300
    $0.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
  }
```

`

I read raywenderlich.com self sizing cell and WTFAutolayout is
[enter link description here](https://www.wtfautolayout.com/?constraintlog=%22%3CSnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x281fab000@FeedCell.swift%23207%20UILabel:0x134433be0.top%20%3D%3D%20UITableViewCellContentView:0x134437b90.top%20%20%2010.0%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CSnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x281fab060@FeedCell.swift%23208%20UILabel:0x134433be0.height%20%3D%3D%2025.0%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CSnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x281fab5a0@FeedCell.swift%23236%20UIStackView:0x1344370d0.top%20%3D%3D%20UILabel:0x134433be0.bottom%20%20%2010.0%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CSnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x281fab840@FeedCell.swift%23243%20UIStackView:0x134437a00.top%20%3D%3D%20UIStackView:0x1344370d0.bottom%20%20%2010.0%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CSnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x281fab960@FeedCell.swift%23245%20UIStackView:0x134437a00.bottom%20%3D%3D%20UITableViewCellContentView:0x134437b90.bottom%20-%2010.0%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x2819478e0%20%27UISV-canvas-connection%27%20UIStackView:0x1344370d0.top%20%3D%3D%20UILabel:0x1344341a0.top%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x281947930%20%27UISV-canvas-connection%27%20V:%5BUILabel:0x1344341a0%5D-(0)-%7C%20%20%20(active,%20names:%20%27%7C%27:UIStackView:0x1344370d0%20)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x2819777a0%20%27UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height%27%20UITableViewCellContentView:0x134437b90.height%20%3D%3D%2044%20%20%20(active)%3E%22)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your layout ***looks*** like you expect it to, this is a common issue with several UI elements - `UIStackView` being one of them.

Auto-layout is calculating the constraints, based on an **expected cell height** of `44.0`. As it is modifying the elements layout, it throws errors / warnings.

Change this:

```
footerStackView.snp.makeConstraints {
  $0.top.equalTo(attachmentView.snp.bottom).offset(10)
  $0.leading.equalTo(nicknameLabel)
  $0.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
}
```

to this:

```
footerStackView.snp.makeConstraints {
  $0.top.equalTo(attachmentView.snp.bottom).offset(10)
  $0.leading.equalTo(nicknameLabel)
  $0.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(10).priority(.required - 1)
}
```

and the messages should go away.

Comment: still got error, and still look fine. where is the height 44 from ?

Answer (score 0):

I changes the `FSpagerView` datasource's didSet code *1)* and FSPagerView's parent Vertical StackView Constraints *2)*

1. Add `setNeedLayout()` Before `laytoutIfNeeded()`

```
didSet {
    pageControl.numberOfPages = attachments.count
    if !attachments.isEmpty {
      imagePagerView.isHidden = false
    } else {
      imagePagerView.isHidden = true
    }
    imagePagerView.reloadData()
    setNeedsLayout() // <-- Add This line
    layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

2. Change `FSPagerView`'s parent Vertical StackView trailing Constraints

```
trailing.equalTo(imagePagerView)
```